# Removing several chars at unknown index

Tags: c#, indexof

so I'm trying to remove several chars at an unknown index in a string.

The purpose of the program is to remove the character before "<".
So for example: *Te<st* should produce the output *Tst* so both E and < is removed from the string.
Also, it should be able to remove several occurrences of the "<".
For example, *This< is<< Text* should produce the output *Thi Text*

I've been trying to work around with char[] and StringBuilder but can't quite seem to get the hang of it.

I'm currently stuck with this code who doesn't do what I want it to do.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
        
        int indexLocation = input.IndexOf("<");
        int RemoveChar = indexLocation - 1; 
        Console.WriteLine(input.Remove(RemoveChar));
```

This doesn't work if the string has more than one "<" and if the "<" is in the middle of a sentence. For example *He<llo* the output is just *h*

Grateful for any answers or tips. I'm a beginner programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution might be to use a `Stack<T>`. That way, when you encounter a `<`, you just pop from the stack.

```
Stack<char> stack = new Stack<char>();

foreach (char c in "This< is<< Text")
{
    if (c == '<')
    {
        if (stack.Any())  // Make sure the stack isn't empty
            stack.Pop();
    }
    else
    {
        stack.Push(c);
    }
}

string output = new string(stack.Reverse().ToArray());
```

Outputs:

```
Thi  Text
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked like a charm. Didn't even know Stack<> was a thing in C#, so I learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do it is to walk backwards through the string and keep track of how many `<` characters you find by incrementing a variable. Then, when we find a different character, if the variable's value is greater than zero, we just decrement it. Otherwise we add the character to the beginning of the string builder:

```
var input = "This< is<< Text";
var output = new StringBuilder();
var charsToSkip = 0;

for (int i = input.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (input[i] == '<')
    {
        charsToSkip++;
    }
    else if (charsToSkip > 0)
    {
        charsToSkip--;
    }
    else
    {
        output.Insert(0, input[i]);
    }
}

input = output.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code Snippet:

```
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        do
        {
            int indexLocation = input.IndexOf("<");
            int RemoveChar = indexLocation - 1; 
            input = input.Remove(RemoveChar, 2);
        } while (Regex.Matches(input,@"<").Count != 0);
        Console.WriteLine(input);
```

The result would be:

[image: result1]

[image]